# Group list of objects by key into list with sublists of unique objects (with java streams)

Tags: java, list, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

I have a list in which I have a combination of key and some additional objects, that are not related to each other in other way.

Considering this structure:

```
record A0(String id, String name, B b, C c) {}

record A(String id, String name, Set<B> bs, Set<C> cs) {}

record B(String id, String name) {}

record C(String id, String name) {}
```

```
a0s.add(new A0("1", "n1", new B("1", "nb1"), new C("1", "nc1")));
a0s.add(new A0("1", "n1", new B("1", "nb1"), new C("2", "nc2")));
a0s.add(new A0("1", "n1", new B("2", "nb2"), new C("3", "nc3")));
a0s.add(new A0("2", "n2", new B("2", "nb2"), new C("4", "nc4")));
a0s.add(new A0("2", "n2", new B("1", "nb1"), new C("5", "nc5")));
a0s.add(new A0("2", "n2", new B("2", "nb2"), new C("6", "nc6")));
a0s.add(new A0("3", "n3", new B("3", "nb3"), new C("7", "nc7")));
a0s.add(new A0("3", "n3", new B("3", "nb3"), new C("8", "nc8")));
a0s.add(new A0("4", "n4", new B("4", "nb4"), new C("9", "nc9")));
a0s.add(new A0("4", "n4", new B("5", "nb5"), new C("10", "nc10")));
```

`I want to achieve this with java-streams:`

```
[ {
  "id" : "1",
  "name" : "n1",
  "bs" : [ {
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "nb1"
  }, {
    "id" : "2",
    "name" : "nb2"
  } ],
  "cs" : [ {
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "nc1"
  }, {
    "id" : "2",
    "name" : "nc2"
  }, {
    "id" : "3",
    "name" : "nc3"
  } ]
}, {
  "id" : "2",
  "name" : "n2",
  "bs" : [ {
    "id" : "2",
    "name" : "nb2"
  }, {
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "nb1"
  } ],
  "cs" : [ {
    "id" : "4",
    "name" : "nc4"
  }, {
    "id" : "5",
    "name" : "nc5"
  }, {
    "id" : "6",
    "name" : "nc6"
  } ]
}, {
  "id" : "3",
  "name" : "n3",
  "bs" : [ {
    "id" : "3",
    "name" : "nb3"
  } ],
  "cs" : [ {
    "id" : "7",
    "name" : "nc7"
  }, {
    "id" : "8",
    "name" : "nc8"
  } ]
}, {
  "id" : "4",
  "name" : "n4",
  "bs" : [ {
    "id" : "4",
    "name" : "nb4"
  }, {
    "id" : "5",
    "name" : "nb5"
  } ],
  "cs" : [ {
    "id" : "10",
    "name" : "nc10"
  }, {
    "id" : "9",
    "name" : "nc9"
  } ]
} ]
```

Here is my code without(obviously) java-streams:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

class Scratch {

  record A0(String id, String name, B b, C c) {}

  record A(String id, String name, Set<B> bs, Set<C> cs) {}

  record B(String id, String name) {}

  record C(String id, String name) {}

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    List<A0> a0s = new ArrayList<>();
    a0s.add(new A0("1", "n1", new B("1", "nb1"), new C("1", "nc1")));
    a0s.add(new A0("1", "n1", new B("1", "nb1"), new C("2", "nc2")));
    a0s.add(new A0("1", "n1", new B("2", "nb2"), new C("3", "nc3")));
    a0s.add(new A0("2", "n2", new B("2", "nb2"), new C("4", "nc4")));
    a0s.add(new A0("2", "n2", new B("1", "nb1"), new C("5", "nc5")));
    a0s.add(new A0("2", "n2", new B("2", "nb2"), new C("6", "nc6")));
    a0s.add(new A0("3", "n3", new B("3", "nb3"), new C("7", "nc7")));
    a0s.add(new A0("3", "n3", new B("3", "nb3"), new C("8", "nc8")));
    a0s.add(new A0("4", "n4", new B("4", "nb4"), new C("9", "nc9")));
    a0s.add(new A0("4", "n4", new B("5", "nb5"), new C("10", "nc10")));

    Set<A> collectA = new HashSet<>();
    Map<String, Set<B>> mapAB = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Set<C>> mapAC = new HashMap<>();

    a0s.forEach(
        a0 -> {
          mapAB.computeIfAbsent(a0.id, k -> new HashSet<>());
          mapAC.computeIfAbsent(a0.id, k -> new HashSet<>());
          mapAB.get(a0.id).add(a0.b);
          mapAC.get(a0.id).add(a0.c);
          collectA.add(new A(a0.id, a0.name, new HashSet<>(), new HashSet<>()));
        });

    Set<A> outA = new HashSet<>();

    collectA.forEach(
        a -> {
          outA.add(new A(a.id, a.name, mapAB.get(a.id), mapAC.get(a.id)));
        });

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    String json =
        objectMapper.writeValueAsString(
            outA.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(A::id))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));

    System.out.println(json);
  }
}
```

I have red posts and docs, but was unable to achieve it.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70598461/list-of-unique-objects-containing-unique-sub-objects) pointed me in some direction, but I was unable to continue combining with other solution and reading API docs.
What "bugs", me is that I have *multiple* repeated objects to group(collect) and be unique. I am using Set to get advantage of the uniqueness, but could be List as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## groupingBy + teeing

One of the way to do that is to build the solution around standard Collectors.

For convince, we can introduce a couple of custom types.

A record which is meant to hold the unique properties `id` and `name`:

```
record IdName(String id, String name) {}
```

And another record for storing sets `Set<B>`, `Set<C>` associated with the same `id`:

```
record BCSets(Set<B> bs, Set<C> cs) {}
```

The logic of the stream:

- Group the data using `IdName` as a Key by utilizing Collector `groupingBy()`
- Make use of Collector `teeing()` as downstream of grouping. `teeing()` expects three arguments: two Collectors and a function combining the results produced by them. As both downstream Collectors of [`teeing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)) we can make use of the combination of `mapping()` and `toSet()`, and combine their results by generating an auxiliary record `BCSets`.
- Then create a stream over the map entries and transform each entry into an instance of type `A`.
- Sort the stream elements and collect them into a list.

```
List<A> listA = a0s.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        a0 -> new IdName(a0.id(), a0.name()),
        Collectors.teeing(
            Collectors.mapping(A0::b, Collectors.toSet()),
            Collectors.mapping(A0::c, Collectors.toSet()),
            BCSets::new
        )
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> new A(e.getKey().id(), e.getKey().name(), e.getValue().bs(), e.getValue().cs()))
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(A::id))
    .toList();
```

## groupingBy + custom Collector

Another option would be to create a custom Collector which would be used as the downstream of `grouping()`

For that, we need to define a custom accumulation type to consume elements from the stream and collect instances of `B` and `C` into sets. For convenience, I've implemented `Consumer` interface:

```
public static class ABCAccumulator implements Consumer<A0> {
    private Set<B> bs = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<C> cs = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public void accept(A0 a0) {
        bs.add(a0.b());
        cs.add(a0.c());
    }
    
    public ABCAccumulator merge(ABCAccumulator other) {
        bs.addAll(other.bs);
        cs.addAll(other.cs);
        return this;
    }
    
    // getters
}
```

To create a custom Collector, we can use static factory method [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...)).

The overall logic remains the same with one difference - now we have only two collectors, and the type of values of auxiliary map is different as well (it would be `ABCAccumulator`).

```
List<A> listA = a0s.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        a0 -> new IdName(a0.id(), a0.name()),
        Collector.of(
            ABCAccumulator::new,
            ABCAccumulator::accept,
            ABCAccumulator::merge
        )
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> new A(e.getKey().id(), e.getKey().name(), e.getValue().getBs(), e.getValue().getCs()))
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(A::id))
    .toList();
```

Comment: Ah.. You beat me to it

Comment: @user7 That's not the only option, it can be done with fewer collectors (I've picked this approach because it was easier to implement).

Comment: This was the only easier way I could think of (other than my solution)

Comment: @user7 Records are introduced with Java 16, hence we are free to apply the latest API features.

Comment: Yes... How did I miss it :D. Maybe because I use records extensively

Comment: @user7 Added the second solution that I've mentioned, without `teeing` (and with fewer collectors).

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Thank you very much! I was stuck with older java projects a long time and haven't used a lot of the added features through the time being. + thanks to user7, also a great solution...

Answer (score 2):

<s>Until I can think of a better approach....</s>

I was writing a solution using `Collectors.teeing`, but [@Alexander Ivanchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74477768) beat me to it. You can refer to that answer for how to achieve this using `Collectors.teeing`.

---

**My initial code without using `Collectors.teeing`**:

First, we group the elements in source list (`a0s`) by their id.

```
Map<String, List<A0>> groupById = a0s.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A0::id));
```

Next, we stream the entries in the previous map and build `A` objects.

```
Set<A> outAResult = groupById.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(entry -> new A(entry.getKey(),
                    entry.getValue().get(0).name(), //since grouped by A0's id - name will be same for all elements
                    transform(entry.getValue(), A0::b),
                    transform(entry.getValue(), A0::c)))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

 private <T> Set<T> transform(List<A0> a0s, Function<A0, T> mapper) {
    return a0s.stream()
            .map(mapper)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

One issue is we have to stream the elements in `List<A0>` (each value in `groupById` map) twice to extract the `List<B>` and `List<C>`.

Note: Extracting the name of A0 object by `entry.getValue().get(0).name()` doesn't look great. To avoid this, you can create a temporary object (a record) which captures the *id* and *name* and group by that.

Comment: One-liners a cute, but when the code is granular it's not bad as well.